# Saving a Var during a configuration change

Tags: android, kotlin, configuration, bundles

On screen rotation, I would like to have the var cardcount saved, so the user is not reset to to the first flash card when they rotate the screen.

I have attempted using the onSaveInstanceState and savedInstanceState.getInt() to keep the keep the value on the rotation, but it does not save the value.

I have seen alternatives to these functions, and I am not sure if I am going down some deep rabbit holes for something simple, or if I am swimming in the wrong ocean entirely.

Should I be looking into ViewModels and persistent storage, taking over manually with configuration  changes, or shared preferences? The data is one variable, in one fragment.

```
class Components : Fragment() {

    //Variables to keep track of which card, as well as which side is showing
    private var cardcount = 0
    private var cardfront = true


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        //This is the function to set the image and text for the front and back of the flashard
        fun select_card() {
            card_front.setImageResource(map.getValue(cardcount).image)
            card_back.text = map.getValue(cardcount).text
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what ViewModel is for.

As per android docs:

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in
> a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive
> configuration changes such as **screen rotations**.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need to use `ViewModel`s if you're not already, and `SharedPreferences` might be too much just for this - but it depends on exactly what you want.

If you just want to keep a value while the app is "open" (including in the background) then the `onSaveInstanceState()` method is made for that. Pop a value in the `Bundle` it provides, and when your fragment needs to restore state it will be passed back in through `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`, `onViewStateRestored`... just pick it up in whichever lifecycle callback is most convenient, check the `Bundle` isn't null (see next part!) and grab the value with the same key you used to store it.

---

If the fragment *isn't* restoring a previous state though, you won't get a bundle passed in. Your app can get closed by the system at any time (say to free up memory), so when it gets restarted, it's meant to look like it was running the whole time - that's why `onSaveInstanceState` gets called, and why you get a bundle passed in, it's so you can put everything back the way it was when it went into the background.

But if the user closes the app, say by swiping it away, the next time you open it will be a fresh start - there's no state to persist, so you won't get the bundle. So if you **do** want to persist state between app runs (say the user's choice of language), you'll need to use something like `SharedPreferences` to store some data, and load that in your Fragment.

---

`ViewModel`s don't survive process death (the system killing your app in the background), so they don't persist state like `onSavedInstanceState` does. They're more for things like configuration changes, where the app is going to stay in the foreground. You still have to be able to handle your state getting lost, and being able to recreate it. There are some other libraries to extend `ViewModel`s to help you handle this but... just use a `Bundle` for an `Int` in my opinion, keep it simple

Definitely don't override configuration changes! That's [a last resort](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes#HandlingTheChange) and your example is like, the basic saved instance `Bundle` use case

Comment: Thanks for the information, I did attempt the onSavedInstanceState but for whatever reason it was not working out. I'm not sure if I was implementing it wrong by placing it in an override function and using the null check in the onViewCreated; but when I clicked build, it showed no issues, and didn't hold or restore the variable. I am going to try using viewModel, it appears to do what I need, and more. Everything I read did steer me away from the manual configuration changes. I will look into bundles more, I am probably doing something wrong. Thanks again.

Comment: The reason I mentioned the state stuff is that if you actually swipe away the app, there's no state to restore - so it depends how you're testing this. And yeah, I'll usually do the restoration in ``onViewCreated`` - it might be worth debugging the app, and setting a breakpoint in that method so you can poke around the ``Bundle`` and see what's actually set in there. Just be careful with what I said about ``ViewModel``s though - if your process is destroyed in the background you'll still lose your state (turn on *Don't keep activities* in your developer options to test how your app handles it)

Comment: I tried the developer option on the app, and see what your talking about. My Var reset back to 0. That will definitely be something utilize,  from this point forward and it really demonstrates how the app will react to onDestroy in the background. Sometimes it's hard to understand something when you can't physically see it.

Comment: Yeah it's just the way Android works - there's no virtual memory (swap file, page file etc) so your app can be completely kicked out of memory, and it has to be able to save and restore its own state. The system handles some of that for you (saving `View` states, scroll positions, text entered into `EditTexts` etc) by using a ``Bundle``, and `onSaveInstanceState` is where it lets you add to that bundle so you can save and restore other things. The idea is you can save simple values like `Int`s and `String`s, and use those to recreate more complex state (including restoring your `ViewModel`)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer IMO for this specific case. Why instantiate a ViewModel just to persist a single variable.